# Add "Add New" button in the last cell of UICollectionCell. (CoreData)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Trying to tackle this issue from different way. 
Current implementation gives me an error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'no object at index 3 in section at index 0'
It occurs at class AppDelegate: UIResponder...

My code is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
    configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    var numberOfItems = self.collectionView(self.collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: 0)

    if (indexPath.row == numberOfItems - 1) {

        var addCellButton = UIButton(frame: cell.frame)
        addCellButton.setTitle("Add", for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.addSubview(addCellButton)
    } 
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = controller.sections {
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects + 1
    }
    return 0
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    if let sections = controller.sections {
        return sections.count
    }
    return 0
}
```

Any advice?

Comment: From your code, it seems like your collectionView has multiple sections and every section has an add button at the end of it. Is this assumption correct? Or should only one of the sections have an add button?

Comment: @Zhang only one section. Add button at the end of the only one section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write it like this to dequeue two separate cells:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView:UICollectionView!
    var items = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Watermelon", "Coconut"]


    ...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        // ------------------------------------------
        // +1 here for the extra add button
        // at the bottom of the collection view
        // ------------------------------------------
        return items.count + 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // --------------------------------
        // IndexPath row vs Items Count
        // --------------------------------
        // [0] = Apple
        // [1] = Banana
        // [2] = Orange
        // [3] = Watermelon
        // [4] = Coconut
        //
        // [5] = special cell
        //
        // ---------------------------------
        let cellID = indexPath.row < items.count ? "normalCell" : "specialCell"

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)

        setupCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath, type: cellID)

        return cell
    }

    func setupCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell, indexPath: IndexPath, type: String) {
        switch(type) {
        case "normalCell":
            setupFruitCell(cell: cell as! FruitCell, indexPath: indexPath)
        case "specialCell":
            setupSpecialCell(cell: cell as! SpecialCell, indexPath: indexPath)
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func setupFruitCell(cell: FruitCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.label.text = items[indexPath.row]
    }

    func setupSpecialCell(cell: SpecialCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.btnAdd.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addButtonTapped), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    }

    func addButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        print("Show UI to add new fruit")
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try creating two cell identifiers. 
The error persisted. 
Is there any way to research this error more? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: rewrote my code to obey your logic, implemented different "configureCell" methods. 
Still had the same error: no object at index 3 in section at index 0.

Comment: What do you see when you print out your data source? For example, in my above code, I would add `print("Items = \(items)")` above my `return items.count + 1` to print out what was actually in the array. Either way, the error you're seeing is telling you your data source has no 4th element (index 3) and you're trying to access that non-existing element, hence the error.

Comment: when i Add print statement to "numberOfItemsInSecton" i see "3" because i have a separate method "createSampleData" where I manually create 3 objects. 
I decided to move on, and just created an "Add" button on NavigationBar.

Answer (score 1):

Do not mess with your cells by adding views to them.  Cells get recycled when they go off screen (thats why its called dequeueReusableCell).  Unless you are removing the extra view in prepare for reuse, they stay on the cell and get added over an over again.  Instead you have 2 other options:

1) Make a second collectionViewCell in interface builder with its own class and reuseIdentifier and deque an instance of this cell only for the last cell.

2) Make the button part of a footer view and return it in [viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/1618037-collectionview?language=objc)

Comment: Trying to dequeue 2 different cells in cellForItemAt:.
How would you suggest to structure "If" statement to target all cell but the last one and then the last one?

Comment: Calculated number of items in section with "numberOfItems(inSection:)"
Ran a condition: if indexPath.item <= numberOfItems - 1 
Still had the same error "'no object at index 3 in section at index 0".
Unfortunately switching to creating an "Add" btn somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sulution : swift 4.2

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       // +1 here for the extra add button
        // bottom of the collection view
        return item.count + 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //initialization cell
        let cells : UICollectionViewCell?

        if indexPath.row < item.count {

         // if indexpath.row < item.count => assign value to cellPet 

            let cellPet = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell1", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1
          // setup data cell  or not
            cellPet.setupView(listPet: item[indexPath.row ])

          // assign values c​​ells
            cells = cellPet

        } else {
            // assign value to cellAdd 
            let cellAdd = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell2
            // setup data cell or not setup

            // assign values c​​ells
            cells = cellAdd
        }
        return cells!
    }
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explanation of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Comment: As @JaimilPatel mentioned, an explanation of your code will be much more helpful for the asker to understand the root cause of problem he was facing. According to me, the problem was with the configureCell() method which was invoked with indexPath not available in core data fetched results. This is because he annually add 1 to number of items he return for section. Your solution is good but an explanation will be helpful to not repeat the same mistakes again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    if indexPath.row < myArr.count {
        cell.configure(with: CollectionModelViewCell(label: myArr[indexPath.row].text))
    } else {
        cell.configure(with: CollectionModelViewCell(label: "+"))
    }
    return cell
}
```