# How add button to end of CollectionView (Not in last Cell)?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, swift4

How can i add button to end of CollectionView **like in app Workflow (Settings button in end)**?

I did not find how to do this.

**Workflow**
[image]

[My app (So big screenshoot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgR5l.png)

Comment: why  you are not adding the button at the last index ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577984/add-button-at-the-end-of-collection-view-in-storyboard/31578251

Comment: @RamMani Because this button will open the application settings

Comment: why you didn't added it in collectionView footer?

Comment: @B2Fq Try this One https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635588/10150796

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved using a `UICollectionView` footerView. Below is an example of how that might work:

First, register your footer view class in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerClass(myFooterViewClass, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer")

}
```

Secondly, either set the `headerReferenceSize` in `collectionViewFlowLayout` or implement `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` in the `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

Thirdly, return the footerView from the `dataSource`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
     let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "myFooterView", forIndexPath: indexPath)

     // Add your button here

     return view
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section != 5 {
            //without button Cell
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            return cell
        } else {
            //with button Cell like setting Click
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            return cell
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 5 {
            //open your viewController in which you want to setting view like.
        }
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth/2, height: screenWidth/3);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.